# Tensorflow Error: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0, yolo

I've looked through previous answers to similar questions but couldn't find the answer that worked for me.

I've worked with TensorFlow for a long time. Currently trying out Yolov4 which has a requirement to use Tensorflow version 2.3.0, so I decided to install that one.

Anaconda's latest release is 2.1.0 that works great on my computer. So since that was not enough, I created a new environment and installed Tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow-gpu` which installs version 2.3.0 seemingly without errors.

Then for the `import tensorflow as tf` I get this error. Any ideas what to try to resolve this?

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mazat\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mazat\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\mazat\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\mazat\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\mazat\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\mazat\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mazat\Anaconda3\envs\tf23\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem was the old version of Redistributable for Visual Studio.
With the new version from here, it seems to work thus far!

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: In my case a solution came from the following. I installed
1. the latest cuda (cuda_11.1.0_456.43_win10.exe from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and
2. vc_redist.x64 package (vc_redist.x64.exe from https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and update Visual Studio (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/downloads/) worked for me.

Comment: Please don't use link only answer. Please provide some example with context. In the future the link may not work, and your answer would be useless