# tensorflow 2.3.1 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've read multiple posts regarding this problem however no luck fixing it.

I am using tensorflow-cpu version 2.3.1, Python 3.7.3. I have downloaded using pip. I keep on getting `ImportError` and not sure what to do from here, most post talks about tensorflow-gpu version.

Here is my full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\haneu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\haneu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\haneu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\haneu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\haneu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haneu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling all Visual Studio previous version and re-installing new one, it got rid of `ImportError` thanks to [Tensorflow Error: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177804/tensorflow-error-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-b)

However after that I kept on getting `ModuleNotFoundError` everytime I've got this, uninstalled that module and re-installed it. My guess is that there were versions not compatible with each other. But anyways it had fixed my problem.